# Visual studio is not highlighting suggestions in C# while typing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Visual Studio was working fine until I close the project, then few hours later when I reopen the Editor and I started to get this strange behavior, usually when I type `return` the auto suggest highlights the keyword so I just hit enter but now it only gets the border of the box.

This is now :

[image]

And This is how it was before :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove `.vs` folder at solution root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following steps for this purpose:

1. From the menu choose **Edit**
2. Then **Intellisense**
3. And finally [Toggle Completion Mode](http://thesoftwareshrink.com/visual-studio/intellisense-completion-vs-suggestion-mode)

You can also hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> as an another alternative. It should now shows full blue color selection.